# ERROR in app: SQL error: readonly attribute

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a flask app that would display a table when you select the start and end dates from the date picker and extract the data by clicking the 'download icon'. The first function (`'index()'`) is correct; it performs the stored procedure ''`CONS_CHECKER`'', which has two parameters,'`startdate`' and '`endate`', and will capture the values from the date picker (start date and end date). The function `download_weekly_data()` failed, and I received the error message ''`ERROR in app: SQL error: readonly attribute'`'. I'm curious how it happened when the first stored procedure works, and they have same functionalities.

when I put print on the start date and end date. The `index()` function displayed the dates selected on the date picker however the `download_weekly_data()` function displayed 'None'.

the Stored procedure and the Select statement have same data type nvarchar(8).

```
20231002
20231002
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2023 09:02:22] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2023 09:02:22] "GET /static/css/ccstyle.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2023 09:02:22] "GET /static/images/banner.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
None
None
ERROR in app: SQL error: readonly attribute
```

App

[image]

APP.py

```
# Define your DateForm for the HTML form
class DateForm(FlaskForm):
    start_date = DateField('Start Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])
    end_date = DateField('End Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])

# Set up a before_request function to store date values
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.start_date_str = None
    g.end_date_str = None

# Define the index route (main page)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = DateForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        start_date = form.start_date.data
        end_date = form.end_date.data

        if end_date < start_date:
            flash('End date cannot be earlier than the start date.', 'error')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        g.start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        g.end_date_str = end_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        
        print( g.start_date_str)
        print( g.start_date_str)

        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("EXEC CONS_CHECKER ?, ?", g.start_date_str, g.end_date_str)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
        except pyodbc.Error as e:
            app.logger.error("SQL error: %s", str(e))
            result = None
        finally:
            cursor.close()

        if result:
            return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=result)
        else:
            flash('No data available for the selected date range.', 'error')

    return render_template('index.html', form=form, data=None)

# Define the download_weekly_data route
@app.route('/download_weekly_data', methods=['GET'])
def download_weekly_data():
    data = request.args.get('data')  # Get the 'data' parameter from the request query string

    # Get the selected start and end dates from the g object
    start_date_str = g.start_date_str
    end_date_str = g.end_date_str

    if data == 'RAWDATA':
        # Execute a direct SQL query to retrieve the data
        sql_query = f"SELECT * FROM RAWDATA WHERE DATE BETWEEN '{start_date_str}' AND '{end_date_str}'"
        
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql_query)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.description = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]  # Define column names
            result = [dict(zip(cursor.description, row)) for row in rows]  # Convert to a list of dictionaries
        except Exception as e:
            app.logger.error("SQL error: %s", str(e))
            result = None
        finally:
            cursor.close()

        if result:
            # Create a Pandas DataFrame from the SQL result
            df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description])

            # Create an Excel file in memory
            excel_file = BytesIO()
            with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

            # Seek back to the beginning of the BytesIO object
            excel_file.seek(0)

            # Return the Excel file as a response with the specified filename
            return send_file(excel_file, as_attachment=True, download_name=f'{data}_{start_date_str}_{end_date_str}.xlsx', mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        else:
            return "No data found."

    elif data == 'CONS':
        # Execute a direct SQL query for the CONS data
        # Similar to the RAWDATA block, use a SQL query
        pass

    else:
        return "Unknown data value"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is the line `cursor.description = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]  # Define column names` supposed to overwrite a read-only property of the [Cursor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor)? In the circumstances, it would be worth putting the abbreviate column names in a separate list and zipping that list on the next line.